# Boost polynomial initialization and access

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use the [Boost.Math polynomial class](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/polynomials.html) and I've come across a few issues I need help with. For reference, here is a [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/boost/math/tools/polynomial.hpp) to the header file contents of that class. Note in particular that the coefficient array is represented using `std::vector`:

```
template <class T>
class polynomial
{
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    std::vector<T> m_data;
};
```

First of all, in some situations, I will be unable to initialize the polynomial when it is declared; my code will later assign coefficients one by one inside a loop. Ideally I'd like to write something like this:

```
boost::math::tools::polynomial<int> f;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    f[i] = /* get value for i-th coefficient somehow */;
}
```

Here is how `operator[]` is implemented in the polynomial class:

```
   value_type& operator[](size_type i)
   {
      return m_data[i];
   }
   const value_type& operator[](size_type i) const
   {
      return m_data[i];
   }
```

So when running my code above, it may result in an out-of-bounds access to the underlying `std::vector` unless I somehow communicate to the class that my polynomial will have degree >= *n*. However, I was unable to find a constructor or a member function to this class allowing to set the size of the `std::vector` (i.e. something similar to the `std::vector`'s `reserve()` member function) unless I supply the data beforehand, which I don't have yet.

I could initialize it with a vector of zeros of the desired size, but this is inefficient (and, in my opinion, ugly). I could also get to the underlying `std::vector` using the `data()` member function of the class and call `reserve()`, but this breaks the abstraction and creates a dependency on the specific implementation using `std::vector` (which is unlikely to change, but still).

Also, I need to read out specific coefficients of a polynomial, and it might happen that I try to access the *i*-th coefficient of a polynomial with degree < *i*. Mathematically speaking, it is reasonable to take such "out-of-bounds" coefficients as zero, but using `operator[]` to access the *i*-th coefficient would result in an out-of-bounds access to the underlying `std::vector`. I could write a wrapper which calls `size()` or `degree()` prior to accessing the representation, which returns zero if the access is out-of-bounds, but again, this seems like very basic functionality which I am surprised if it's not implemented.

In general, I'd like to ask: am I missing something or is this library really, really bare-bones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`polynominal::data` member function returns a reference to this vector, so altering it is a trivial matter:

```
f.data().resize(n);
```

Comment: Agreed this works, but like I mentioned in my question, it breaks the abstraction. Say a later version moves away from `std::vector` to a different container which doesn't implement `resize()`, then this would break.

Comment: @swineone Yes, if they move away from `std::vector` then it would mean breaking a public interface. So this probably won't happen unless they have a serious reason to.